# How to send a blank file in multipart request

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I am unable to send a blank file using http request in flutter.
The server is giving me exception '500'.
Also I need to send a parameter "Filename" cuz it's not optional, otherwise I can just skip it if file is null.

here's the code:

```
  final Uri _saveTaskUrl =
      Uri.parse('http://————————);

  Future addNewTask(
      {File image,
      taskName,}) async {
// Intilize the multipart request
final imageUploadRequest = http.MultipartRequest('POST', _saveTaskUrl);

// Attach the file in the request

  final mimeTypeData =
      lookupMimeType(image?.path ?? '', headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8])
          .split('/');

   //Error is here
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   //what to do here if i want to send a blank image file
  final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('FileName', image?.path ?? ''
      ,contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]));
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  imageUploadRequest.files.add( file);


imageUploadRequest.headers.addAll({
  "token": centralstate.loginData["AuthToken"],
  "clientid": centralstate.loginData["ClientId"].toString(),

});


    imageUploadRequest.fields['taskName'] = taskName;


    try {

      final streamedResponse = await imageUploadRequest.send();
      final response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {

        print(
            'Error while adding new task : ${response.statusCode} : ${response.body}');
        return 0;
      }


      print(responseData);

      return 1;
    } catch (e) {

      return 0;
    }
  }
```

from the blank file I mean something like this:
Screenshot from the postman
[image: Postman Screenshot]

I know I can use if statement to check file!=null, but I explicitly want to send a blank file.

Comment: Have you tried the `MultipartFile.fromBytes` constructor, with a zero length byte array?

Comment: @RichardHeap I have tried this one :   http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('FileName', [],
          contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]));

Comment: And what happened? Did it work? Did you check the transmitted data using a packet capture. (You can test using a pure Dart project on any machine if that's easier to grab a capture.)

Comment: No, it's still giving me exception 500 : Internal Server Error Occurred.Though thanks for the suggestion.Since I cannot find any solution, i have told my API developer to make this parameter optional.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest(
    "POST",
    Uri.parse(baseUrl + "api/profiles/v1/update/"),
  )
    ..fields['first_name'] = firstName
    ..fields['last_name'] = lastName
    ..fields['phone'] = phone
    ..fields['full_name'] = fullName
    ..fields['country'] = 'Uzbekistan'
    ..fields['city'] = 'Tashkent'
    ..fields['date_birth'] = dateBirth!;

  if (req.image == null) {
    request.fields['image'] = '';
  } else {
    var picture = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'image',
      req.image!,
      filename: req.image!.split('/').last,
    );
    request.files.add(picture);
  }
  var response = await request.send();
  var responsed = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
  print(responsed.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a blank file you can use this

```
 request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('field-name', [],
            contentType: MediaType('image', 'png'), filename: ''));
```

Import this

```
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

This is my complete code

```
  Future<http.Response> multiPartRequest(
  {required Map<String, String> multiPartBody,
  required List<File?> multiPartFile}) async {
var url = Uri.parse("your-base-url/your-endpoint");
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);

request.fields.addAll(multiPartBody);

int cnt = 1;
for (var file in multiPartFile) {
  if (file != null) {
    String filename = file.path.split('/').last;
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        'file$cnt', file.path,
        filename: filename));
  } else {
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file$cnt', [],
        contentType: MediaType('image', 'png'), filename: ''));
  }
  cnt++;
}

var streamedResponse = await request.send();
var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
debugPrint(response.body);
return response; 
}
```